# SSIS package running on 32 bit machine unable to connect to 64 bit sql server

Tags: ssis

My SSIS package is running on a 32 bit machine and remotely connecting to a sql server which was 32 bit but ugraded to 64. After upgrading when i run the SSIS it errors out with time out error. Its not able to connect to the sql server.

Comment: When the remote instance was upgraded, did they create a new/different named instance? Can you connect to the 64 bit instance from the current machine via sqlcmd? `sqlcmd -S remoteServer -d master -Q "SELECT 1 AS test"`

Comment: The server name was changed but i am using dynamic connection using connection string

Answer (score 0):

This could help
"running-32-bit-ssis-in-a-64-bit-environment"

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/24/running-32-bit-ssis-in-a-64-bit-environment.aspx